# Updated alternative to mongoid_voteable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm looking for some kind of reputation system that allows you to up and down vote posts, and I cam across mongoid_voteable which looks like a good resource, except it doesn't work for rails 4.

Does anybody know any alternative gem, that allows you to do this whilst using mongoid?

Comment: which mongoid version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I have used this gem (this version from the github repo) in a Rails 4 application.

https://github.com/manusajith/mongoid_vote